# Assuming ASP.NET and form upload, any way to ensure file is an image?

Tags: asp.net, system.drawing.imaging

Is there any way to tell if the file is an image either through MIME type or some other way of inspection?  The images are going into a gallery and I'll be resizing them as necessary and want to ensure, to the best I can, that the file I'm about to process with GDI is, in fact, an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to load the file into a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) object.  If if you get an exception then it isn't an image.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question/answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481743/how-can-i-determine-a-files-true-extension-type-programatically) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916770/asp-net-file-upload-validation). I belive this is a duplicate question.

Also, look into reading a file's [magic number](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file%5Fsigs.html) especially if you are just trying to determine if the file is one of a few acceptable types. [Magic number Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic%5Fnumber%5F%28programming%29)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the fileUploadCtrl.PostedFile.ContentType property and compare that string to an expected list of image MIME types i.e. image/gif. You can also perform additional validation by loading the uploaded image bytes into a System.Drawing.Image object. If it loads you know you have a good image, if it fails to load then perhaps the image is a forgery or an unknown format.