# Get extension and size from file uploaded to php-file with file_get_contents

Tags: php, jquery, xmlhttprequest, file-get-contents

I'm trying to figure out how to determine what extension a file has when I receive it using `$content = file_get_contents("php://input");`. I use jQuery to send it to *upload.php* as a POST request (xhr).

I include the filename, size and type in a request header but I don't know how to fetch the header from `file_get_contents()`.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [magic number database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024441/determining-filetype-with-php-what-is-magic-database)

Comment: @mseifert and for `$filename` in that case I simply input `php://input`?

Comment: Examine the first few bytes of $content and interpret it as a header for a finite set of known filetypes. Another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481743/how-can-i-determine-a-files-true-extension-type-programatically?lq=1)

Comment: Do you have any example code or anything because I honestly have no clue on how to write that code.. @mseifert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example using test files. Substitute `$content` from `$content = file_get_contents()` in your example. You can find signatures for other file types [here](http://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search). I chose to convert the first 12 characters to hex of each file. If you have file signatures that are longer, you can increase that number. For file size, you can use `strlen($content)` or try `filesize("php://input")`

```
<?php
    $content = file_get_contents("testjpg.jpg");
    $a = strToHex($content, 12);
    var_dump($a);
    echo getfiletype($a) . "<br>";

    $content = file_get_contents("testdoc.doc");
    $a = strToHex($content, 12);
    var_dump($a);
    echo getfiletype($a) . "<br>";

    $content = file_get_contents("testpdf.pdf");
    $a = strToHex($content, 12);
    var_dump($a);
    echo getfiletype($a) . "<br>";


function getfiletype($test){
    if (testsig($test, "FF D8 FF")){
        return "jpeg";
    }
    elseif (testsig($test, "25 50 44 46")){
        return "pdf";
    }
    elseif (testsig($test, "D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1")){
        return "doc";
    }
    else{
        return "unknown";
    }
}

function testsig($test, $sig){
    // remove spaces in sig
    $sig = str_replace(" ","", $sig);
    if (substr($test, 0, strlen($sig)) == $sig){
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}



function strToHex($string, $stop=null){
    $hex = "";
    if ($stop == null){
        $stop = strlen($string);
    }
    $stop = min(strlen($string), $stop);

    for ($i=0; $i<$stop; $i++){
        $ord = ord($string[$i]);
        $hexCode = dechex($ord);
        $hex .= substr('0'.$hexCode, -2);
    }
    return strtoupper($hex);
}
?>
```

The result of the code is:

```
string 'FFD8FFE1034D457869660000' (length=24)

jpeg

string 'D0CF11E0A1B11AE100000000' (length=24)

doc

string '255044462D312E360D25E2E3' (length=24)

pdf
```